# CentOS 7 : TCSH Shell : How to use tab key for autocompletion but without increasing terminal log history

Tags: linux, terminal, centos-7, tcsh, tab-key

Please forgive if this has addressed before. I couldn't find the solution or I may not be able to phrase the question correctly.
This is my first question to the community.

I am using CentOS7 and tcsh terminal.
In the terminal, when trying to get to a directory or file, I type few characters and then I press tab key, so it auto completes the file/directory name, and if there are multiple names matching first few characters, then it shows the full list of all possible names.

Issue here is that, this list will be printed on my terminal, and if I hit tab-tab again it spits the whole list again, and my terminal log increases.
So now if I have to look at previous command output, I have to scroll up in terminal.

Is there a way to display this possible file/directory list but it would not add to terminal log?

Example:

```
% ls 
file098345    file3544.t    fileasdf      filepoiuasdf  filexcvxc     
% vi file<Tab>
file098345    file3544.t    fileasdf      filepoiuasdf  filexcvxc  
% vi file<Tab>
file098345    file3544.t    fileasdf      filepoiuasdf  filexcvxc  
% vi file<Tab>
file098345    file3544.t    fileasdf      filepoiuasdf  filexcvxc  
% vi file<Tab>
file098345    file3544.t    fileasdf      filepoiuasdf  filexcvxc  
% vi file<Tab>
file098345    file3544.t    fileasdf      filepoiuasdf  filexcvxc  
% vi file<Tab>
file098345    file3544.t    fileasdf      filepoiuasdf  filexcvxc
```

So, if I keep pressing the tab, it will fill my whole screen with above msgs.

What I want is, when I press  it should show possible list, and as I start typing it should go away. So it doesn't add to my terminal screen.

Thank you.